Probability that $X+Y$ and $X+Z$ are less than $1$

Three random numbers $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independently and uniformly picked between $0$ and $1$. What is the probability that $X+Y$ and $X+Z$ are less than $1$?

I know probability of $X+Y+Z <1$ is $\frac{1}{6}$. I wrote a code and simulated the problem and it gave me a probability of $\frac{1}{3}.$ How can I solve this?

What have you tried so far apart from writing a code? How did you solve the case of $X + Y + Z < 1$?

Hint: condition on the value of $X$.

From this post.

I tried $ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-X}dy dx $ and $ \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-X}dz dx $ and got $\frac{1}{2}$ for both of them. How can I progress further?

Something that helps in this type of problem can be visualized readily. For instance, consider just $X$ and $Y$, can use the unit square to find the region of the unit square which will satisfy $x+y<1$. It extends naturally in one additional dimension when considering $Z$ as well.

@ShsTht You want the probability for both at once.  $\iiint_{y=1-x,z=1-x} f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z),\mathrm dz,\mathrm dy,\mathrm dx$

By the law of total expectation
$$
\mathbb{P}(X+Y\le 1, X+Z\le 1)=
\mathbb{E}_x\left[\mathbb{P}(X+Y\le 1, X+Z\le 1\mid X=x)\right]
=
\mathbb{E}_x\left[\mathbb{P}(Y\le 1-x, Z\le 1-x\mid X=x)\right]
=
\mathbb{E}_x\left[\mathbb{P}(Y\le 1-x)\mathbb{P}(Z\le 1-x)\right]
=
\mathbb{E}_x\left[(1-x)^2\right]
=\int_0^1 (1-x)^2 \cdot  1\mathrm{d}x=\frac13.
$$
